# CMake unable to find_package components with -G Ninja

Tags: cmake, ninja

I'm trying to setup a CMake project using the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(
  stuff
  VERSION 0.0.0
  LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS log)
```

Running `cmake ..` succeeds:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS log
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_headers-1.74.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_log 1.74.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake)
-- Found boost_log 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_log-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_log-1.74.0/libboost_log-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_log-1.74.0/libboost_log-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_log-1.74.0/libboost_log-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log.a
-- Adding boost_log dependencies: atomic;chrono;filesystem;regex;thread;headers
-- Found boost_atomic 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_atomic-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_atomic-1.74.0/libboost_atomic-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_atomic-1.74.0/libboost_atomic-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_atomic.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_atomic-1.74.0/libboost_atomic-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic.a
-- Adding boost_atomic dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_chrono 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_chrono-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_chrono-1.74.0/libboost_chrono-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_chrono-1.74.0/libboost_chrono-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_chrono.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_chrono-1.74.0/libboost_chrono-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono.a
-- Adding boost_chrono dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.74.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem.a
-- Adding boost_filesystem dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_regex 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_regex.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_regex-1.74.0/libboost_regex-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex.a
-- Adding boost_regex dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_thread 1.74.0 at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0
-- Boost toolset is gcc11 (GNU 11.4.0)
-- Scanning /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant*.cmake
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread.so.1.74.0
--   Including /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_thread-1.74.0/libboost_thread-variant-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread.a
-- Adding boost_thread dependencies: atomic;headers
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.74.0") found components: log 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: path/to/stuff/build
```

Running `cmake .. -G Ninja` outputs the following:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1673 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.77.0;1.77;1.76.0;1.76;1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1674 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1675 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1676 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1678 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1712 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1713 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1714 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1715 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1787 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1788 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_77_0;boost_1_77_0;boost/boost-1_77_0;boost/boost_1_77_0;boost-1_77;boost_1_77;boost/boost-1_77;boost/boost_1_77;boost-1_76_0;boost_1_76_0;boost/boost-1_76_0;boost/boost_1_76_0;boost-1_76;boost_1_76;boost/boost-1_76;boost/boost_1_76;boost-1_75_0;boost_1_75_0;boost/boost-1_75_0;boost/boost_1_75_0;boost-1_75;boost_1_75;boost/boost-1_75;boost/boost_1_75;boost-1_74_0;boost_1_74_0;boost/boost-1_74_0;boost/boost_1_74_0;boost-1_74;boost_1_74;boost/boost-1_74;boost/boost_1_74;boost-1_73_0;boost_1_73_0;boost/boost-1_73_0;boost/boost_1_73_0;boost-1_73;boost_1_73;boost/boost-1_73;boost/boost_1_73;boost-1_72_0;boost_1_72_0;boost/boost-1_72_0;boost/boost_1_72_0;boost-1_72;boost_1_72;boost/boost-1_72;boost/boost_1_72;boost-1_71_0;boost_1_71_0;boost/boost-1_71_0;boost/boost_1_71_0;boost-1_71;boost_1_71;boost/boost-1_71;boost/boost_1_71;boost-1_70_0;boost_1_70_0;boost/boost-1_70_0;boost/boost_1_70_0;boost-1_70;boost_1_70;boost/boost-1_70;boost/boost_1_70;boost-1_69_0;boost_1_69_0;boost/boost-1_69_0;boost/boost_1_69_0;boost-1_69;boost_1_69;boost/boost-1_69;boost/boost_1_69;boost-1_68_0;boost_1_68_0;boost/boost-1_68_0;boost/boost_1_68_0;boost-1_68;boost_1_68;boost/boost-1_68;boost/boost_1_68;boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost/boost-1_46_1;boost/boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost/boost-1_46_0;boost/boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost/boost-1_46;boost/boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost/boost-1_45_0;boost/boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost/boost-1_45;boost/boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost/boost-1_44_0;boost/boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost/boost-1_44;boost/boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost/boost-1_43_0;boost/boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost/boost-1_43;boost/boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost/boost-1_42_0;boost/boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost/boost-1_42;boost/boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost/boost-1_41_0;boost/boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost/boost-1_41;boost/boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost/boost-1_40_0;boost/boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost/boost-1_40;boost/boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost/boost-1_39_0;boost/boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost/boost-1_39;boost/boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost/boost-1_38_0;boost/boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost/boost-1_38;boost/boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost/boost-1_37_0;boost/boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost/boost-1_37;boost/boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost/boost-1_36_1;boost/boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost/boost-1_36_0;boost/boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost/boost-1_36;boost/boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost/boost-1_35_1;boost/boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost/boost-1_35_0;boost/boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost/boost-1_35;boost/boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost/boost-1_34_1;boost/boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost/boost-1_34_0;boost/boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost/boost-1_34;boost/boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost/boost-1_33_1;boost/boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost/boost-1_33_0;boost/boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1803 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1843 ] Boost_VERSION = "107400"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1844 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.74.0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1845 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107400"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1846 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1847 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "74"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1848 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1849 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1873 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1874 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-gcc11" (guessed)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1910 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1988 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "" (detected)
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1992 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1993 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2053 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "/usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2054 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "/usr/include/lib;/usr/include/../lib;/usr/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_log-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_log-gcc11-mt;boost_log-gcc11-mt;boost_log-mt-1_74;boost_log-mt;boost_log-mt;boost_log-mt;boost_log
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for LOG_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_log-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_log-gcc11-mt-d;boost_log-gcc11-mt-d;boost_log-mt-d-1_74;boost_log-mt-d;boost_log-mt-d;boost_log-mt;boost_log
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt;boost_date_time-mt-1_74;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d;boost_date_time-gcc11-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d-1_74;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt-d;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt;boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt;boost_log_setup-mt-1_74;boost_log_setup-mt;boost_log_setup-mt;boost_log_setup-mt;boost_log_setup
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt-d;boost_log_setup-gcc11-mt-d;boost_log_setup-mt-d-1_74;boost_log_setup-mt-d;boost_log_setup-mt-d;boost_log_setup-mt;boost_log_setup
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt;boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-1_74;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt-d;boost_filesystem-gcc11-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d-1_74;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt-d;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_thread-gcc11-mt;boost_thread-gcc11-mt;boost_thread-mt-1_74;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d;boost_thread-gcc11-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d-1_74;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt-d;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_regex-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_regex-gcc11-mt;boost_regex-gcc11-mt;boost_regex-mt-1_74;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_regex-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_regex-gcc11-mt-d;boost_regex-gcc11-mt-d;boost_regex-mt-d-1_74;boost_regex-mt-d;boost_regex-mt-d;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt;boost_chrono-mt-1_74;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d;boost_chrono-gcc11-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d-1_74;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt-d;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2239 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-1_74;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt;boost_atomic-mt-1_74;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2294 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d-1_74;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d;boost_atomic-gcc11-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt-d-1_74;boost_atomic-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt-d;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: log) (found version "1.74.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2360 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:11 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/sh/ws/stuff/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Why does find_package fail with Ninja?

Comment: In the first invocation (`cmake ..`) `find_package(Boost)` uses **config script** in the  directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0`. Probably, you have specified this directory in `Boost_DIR` variable or similar. That script has paths to all Boost components. In the second invocation (`cmake .. -G Ninja`) the config script has not been found, so CMake uses `FindBoost.cmake` script shipped with CMake itself. That script has found the header file with the Boost version, but it has failed to find Boost libraries. Probably, libraries are located at non-default location.

Comment: I installed libboost with `apt install libboost-all-dev` and `Boost_DIR` is not set. So the libraries should be located in default locations.

Comment: Run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` option in both cases. That way CMake will print where it searches `BoostConfig.cmake` (that search is successful in the first case but is failed in the second one).

Comment: I get a list of the directories it searches in. If I run `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and then `cmake`, it is able to find Boost. But it's still unable to find other packages. Why aren't the same directories searched in Ninja as with default Makefiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to me having set `NINJA_STATUS=$(echo -e "\033[1;33m%e [%f/%t] (%r)\033[0m ")` as I wanted my format my ninja build with colors. Apparently this breaks finding of libraries. Removing the `\033[Xm`s resolved the issue.